# Notepad++ Python Script to change encoding bug on first line

Tags: python, utf-8, notepad++

Notepad++ v.6.7.7
Notepad Python Script v1.0.8.0

I'm using the following code to open a txt file in `UTF-8` that has filenames, the filenames are of the structure ABCD.ABCDEFG.AB.XXXX where XXXX is the file extension with only letters, the rest of the filename can contain either letters or numbers.

I then iterate thru the files, open them, change the encoding to UTF-8 and then save them.

This has worked already, however in the first line, I'm getting a `Create new file 
<filepath>  doesn't exist, create it?` although the file exists and it's being changed.  I'm not getting any error in the console

I'd appreciate any pointers as to why this behaviour is happening only on the first line.

```
import os;
import sys;
root="\\\\SERVER\\FOLDER"
fname="C:\\filewithfilenames.txt"
myfile=open(fname,"r")
myfilelines = list(myfile)
for line in myfilelines:
    line = line.strip('\r')
    line = line.strip('\n')
    if line[-5:] == '.ABCD':
        notepad.open(root + "\\" + line)
        console.write(line + " CONVERTED TO UTF-8\r\n")
        notepad.runMenuCommand("Encoding", "Convert to UTF-8")
        notepad.save()
        notepad.close()
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message you get and content of `filewithfilenames.txt`?

Comment: @TúlioF. I'm not getting any errors in the console, just the standard create file dialog in notepad++  ABCD.ABCDEFG.AB.XXXX where XXXX is the file extension with only letters, the rest of the filename can contain either letters or numbers.

Comment: Does it always happen on the first line, no matter what the input file is?  If you answer "Yes" to the dialog, do you get an extra file?  The first thing that occurs to me is an invisible character, like a blank at the end of the file name in the input file.

Comment: @saulspatz yes it always happens on the first line.  I only get the files processed and I don't get an extra file, since I have to manually discard the dialog by saying no to the create file dialog.  I converted it to hex but I only see the first char e.g. L 43 and nothing else

Comment: @Jose R Odd. Do I understand you right?  All files in the input get converted to utf-8, and that first dialog seems to relate to some non-existent file?

Comment: @saulspatz that's the tricky  part, the file does  exist but it's asking to create the file, but only on the first line

Comment: @Jose R I'm not sure I understand exactly what's happening. Say the first line is "myFile.ABCD"  Am I right that the message will say, "myFile.ABCD" does not exist?  After you have closed the dialog, can you tell whether myFile.ABCD has been converted to UTF8?   Can you try this with a one-line input file?

Comment: Yes, file has been converted to utf-8 after I close the dialog. I tried with a one line input with and without a new line after it, it still asked the dialog

Comment: I'm out of ideas.  I wish I had a Windows platform so I could try it myself.  Sorry I can't be of any help.